# how to fix "Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable"?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

```
import json
Video={}
Video['url'] = urls
Video['title'] = titles
Video['views'] = views

with open("Video.json", "w") as write_file:
  json.dump(Video, write_file)
```

`
I made  a dict which has a particular channel details and want  into json file but repeatedly shows **Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable**. I implemented using **default parameter** and even tried to **switch the python set into a different data type that is JSON  serializable**.

Comment: Can you show where and how you declare the urls, titles and views?

Comment: titles=soup.find_all('yt-formatted-string', class_='style-scope ytd-rich-grid-media')
views=soup.find_all('span', class_='inline-metadata-item style-scope ytd-video-meta-block')
urls=soup.find_all('yt-formatted-string', class_='style-scope ytd-rich-grid-media')

Answer (score 0):

Seems the Tag type you are using is missing the functions to make them JSON serializable.

In order to make a class JSON serializable in Python, you need to define two methods:

- ****init****
- **to_json**

The **init** method is used to initialize the object, and the to_json method should return a dictionary representation of the object that can be converted to JSON.

Apart from that, the snippet you posted works fine.